# Method overloading in implicit class

Tags: scala

I'm using a class (that I cannot modify) containing a method which receives a value of type Any as parameter, like the following example:

```scala
class Foo(value: Int) {
  def +(other: Any): Foo = ???
}
```

I would like to add a custom implementation for the method `+()` when it's used with a specific type. I would expect to be able to do something like:

```scala
implicit class RichFoo(foo: Foo) {
  def +(other: Int): Foo = ???
}

// or

implicit class RichFoo(foo: Foo) {
  def +[T <: Bar](other: T): T = ???
}
```

However, these approaches don't work.

Is it possible to do without extending the original class?

Comment: What you need are type classes. They allow ad-hoc polymorphism, that is, having a custom implementation for some method depending on which type is used. I'm sure someone will write up an apropriate response, but in the meantime google them up (my article is [here](https://medium.com/byte-code/ad-hoc-polymorphism-and-type-classes-442ae22e5342#.uzzaez54y) but read whatever appeals to you the most). EDIT: I am counting on the fact that you are able to modify class `Foo`.

Comment: @slouc Thank's for your input. The article seems nice, I will take a look at it later. Unfortunately, I'm not able to change Foo, it's implemented by a library I'm using, that's why I'm using an implicit class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

To the compiler, implicit conversions and other rewrite rules (like those around `Dynamic`) are a "last resort" of sorts. They are only applied if code does not already typecheck as-is. When you do `foo + x`, the compiler already knows that `+` takes `Any`, so it doesn't even try to look for implicits. If you did `foo - x`, and `Foo` had no `-` of the correct type, only then would the compiler search for a conversion.

Instead, you can create a method with a new name, maybe `add`, that is not present in `Foo` but is present in `RichFoo`. This will not, however, protect you from doing `foo + 1` instead of `foo add 1`, since both methods are valid.

```
implicit class RichFoo(foo: Foo) {
  def add(other: Int): Foo = ???
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a phantom type to track what is convertible.

```
scala> trait Tagged[B]
defined trait Tagged

scala> type Of[+A, B] = A with Tagged[B]
defined type alias Of

scala> class Tagger[B] { def apply[A](a: A): A Of B = a.asInstanceOf[A Of B] }
defined class Tagger

scala> object tag { def apply[B]: Tagger[B] = new Tagger[B] }
defined object tag
```

The given thing:

```
scala> case class C(i: Int) { def +(x: Any): C = C(i + x.toString.toInt) }
defined class C
```

and a marker trait:

```
scala> trait CC
defined trait CC
```

Normally:

```
scala> C(42) + "17"
res0: C = C(59)
```

This works:

```
scala> val cc = tag[CC](C(42))
cc: Of[C,CC] = C(42)
```

But not this:

```
scala> val cc = tag[CC](C(42): Any)
java.lang.ClassCastException: C cannot be cast to Tagged
  ... 29 elided
```

Maybe this:

```
scala> val cc = tag[CC](C(42): Serializable)
cc: Of[Serializable,CC] = C(42)
```

Then:

```
scala> implicit class XC(v: Serializable Of CC) {
     | def +(x: Any): C Of CC = tag[CC] {
     |   println("OK")
     |   v.asInstanceOf[C] + x
     | }}
defined class XC
```

Abnormally:

```
scala> val valueAdded = cc + "17"
OK
valueAdded: Of[C,CC] = C(59)
```

There's surely a better way to do this:

```
scala> implicit def untagit(x: Serializable Of CC): C Of CC = tag[CC](x.asInstanceOf[C]) 
untagit: (x: Of[Serializable,CC])Of[C,CC]

scala> cc.i
res9: Int = 42
```

because that ruins it:

```
scala> val res: C = cc + "17"
<console>:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : <refinement>.type (with underlying type Of[Serializable,CC])
 required: ?{def +(x$1: ? >: String("17")): ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method XC of type (v: Of[Serializable,CC])XC
 and method untagit of type (x: Of[Serializable,CC])Of[C,CC]
 are possible conversion functions from <refinement>.type to ?{def +(x$1: ? >: String("17")): ?}
       val res: C = cc + "17"
                    ^
<console>:18: error: value + is not a member of Of[Serializable,CC]
       val res: C = cc + "17"
                       ^
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but this approach would add too much complexity for my code, and I decided to just give another name to the new functions, so I'm accepting the other answer.

Comment: Good for you. We forgot to say that overloading is evil anyway.